# Java : set a Component on top of another

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I am writing a program in java. I have a main JPanel that has two JPanel and one Canvas added on it. I aim to resize the Canvas while running the program. When I maximized the Canvas i want it to be always on top of the other component. 

How can I set this property for my Canvas?

Comment: I assume that you're talking about mixing the AWT component Canvas with Swing components, and that begs the question, why?  Are you sure that you really want to do this and are you aware of the tricks and traps involved?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You could replace your main JPanel with a JLayeredPanel. A layered panel will let you specify that some child components should be layered above other child components.

I.e.:

```
    JLayeredPane pane = new JLayeredPane();

    JLabel ontop = new JLabel("On top");
    JLabel behind = new JLabel("Behind");

    pane.add(ontop, 2, 0);
    pane.add(behind, 1, 0);
```

Answer (score 7):

Make your main JPanel a [JLayeredPane](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JLayeredPane.html)

Then you can set the layer of the other components with `setLayer(Component c, int layer)` thus allowing them to overlap.